# Differentiate Nodes in selenium grid-python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-grid

I have multiple nodes and few of them are same OS and Browser combinations(I had it like that some reason).

Now, How do I differentiate on which node to run in my code

```
wd = webdriver.Remote(command_executor = 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

remote driver above will run Chrome browser machine

```
  wd = webdriver.Remote(command_executor = 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

remote driver above will run Firefox machine

what if I have another machine with same browser and I want my another test run on that machine.

How do I differentiate?

Answer (score 0):

The selenium grid determines for you which node is available, and runs it on that node, you don't do this yourself. If your grid has two nodes available, both having a firefox browsers attached, then either one of them can be used. This is the whole point of the grid.

Comment: can I explicitly ask Grid to which one to choose when having same browser combinations? by desired capabilities or something??

Comment: This plugin provides a way to explicitly choose a node via labels, I do not know how this works in pure selenium but it must be possible. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

Comment: Even I know that from kawaguchi's presentation but I also couldn't figure out how to differentiate by label

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.

Comment: @motobrockers I mean to say that , even I came across the selenium plugin but could not understand the way to explicitly choose a node via labels.